# How can I increase the number of bookmarks shown in the Chrome omnibox?

Tags: google-chrome

When searching through the Chrome omnibox, I would like to increase the number of search results shown. Is this possible?

Please take the following example as a reference:

[image]

Comment: There actually used to be a way to increase the number of results in the omnibar but it got removed: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8694725/increasing-the-number-of-suggests-shown-in-omnibox

Comment: @MC10 Pity. Thanks for sharing the referenced discussion!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems that this functionality got reintroduced, albeit in a limited way (max 12 results)

Citing from:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/47806290/2453661

> chrome://flags/#omnibox-ui-max-autocomplete-matches lets you select a
>   maximum of 12 rows.

I tried it and it worked (Chrome Version 64.0.3282.119).